# Weird behavior of getUserMedia

Tags: javascript

I want to record audio using javascript and here is what I have right now:

```js
let audioChunks = [];
let rec;
document.head.innerHTML += '<audio id="recordedAudio" crossorigin="anonymous"></audio>';
const recordedAudio = document.getElementById('recordedAudio');
navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({audio:true}).then(stream => {
    rec = new MediaRecorder(stream);
    rec.ondataavailable = e => {
        audioChunks.push(e.data);
        if(rec.state == "inactive") {
            let blob = new Blob(audioChunks,{type:'audio/x-mpeg-3'});
            recordedAudio.src = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        }
    }
}).catch(e=>console.log(e));

function initRecording() {
    console.log('initRecording');
    audioChunks = [];
    if(rec.state == 'recording') rec.stop();
    rec.start();  
}

function playRecording() {
    console.log('playRecording wait 1 seconds');
    if(rec.state == 'recording') rec.stop();
    setTimeout(() => recordedAudio.play(), 1000);
}

const onStartRecording = event => {  
    if (event.keyCode == 32) {
        event.preventDefault();
        initRecording();
    }
}
document.addEventListener('keydown', onStartRecording);

const onStopRecording = event => {  
    if (event.keyCode == 13) {
        event.preventDefault();
        playRecording();
    }
}
document.addEventListener('keydown', onStopRecording);
```

when you press Space Bar on your keyboard the `initRecording` executes and starts  to record the voice and after that you should press Enter key to execute `playRecording` function and play the recorded voice right?

Ok so far so good but there is a really weird issue with this code:

Press Space and  execute `initRecording` function and say 'One' loudly to record your voice.

Right after this press Space again (this should stop the last recording and start  a new recoding session right?) and say 'Two'.

Now press Enter and hear the recorded voice. As you pressed space I expect to hear only 'Two' but you'll hear the whole voice of One and Two !!!! the more weird part is If you press Enter again you only hear "Two" !!!! Why is this happening and How can I config the code to only hear Two by the explained process of recording?

Comment: My initial guess was that the `ondataavailable` handler is closing over `audioChunks`' initial ref, but that doesn't explain the `[Enter]` behavior--but I'd start there first.

Comment: This is solving the problem: `if(rec.state == "inactive") {
            audioChunks.push(e.data);
            let blob = new Blob(audioChunks,{type:'audio/x-mpeg-3'});
            recordedAudio.src = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        }`

Comment: I can't read that, but seems reasonable. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaStream_Recording_API/Using_the_MediaStream_Recording_API explicitly creates new blobs as well.